# Filter data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data

```
     id       date                  sec        buy
5211153  2016-06-13 18:48:55             119    1  
5211153  2016-06-13 18:50:54              66    0  
5211153  2016-06-13 18:57:09               2    1  
5211154  2016-06-13 18:57:12             118    0  
5211154  2016-06-13 18:59:08              20    0  
5211154  2016-06-13 18:59:34              25    0  
5211154  2016-06-13 18:59:59              11    0  
5211154  2016-06-13 19:00:11              12    1
```

I want to print all data where `buy = 0` before every `buy = 1`.
I try this code

```
for i, (id, date, buy) in enumerate(zip(ids, dates, buys)):
    if buys[i] == 1:
         print ids[i], dates[i]
         while buys[i-1] != 1:
            print dates[i - 1], buys[i - 1]
```

But it return not what I want
Desire output:

```
5211153  2016-06-13 18:57:09      1:
5211153  2016-06-13 18:50:54  
5211154  2016-06-13 19:00:11      1:
5211154  2016-06-13 18:57:12   
5211154  2016-06-13 18:59:08     
5211154  2016-06-13 18:59:34    
5211154  2016-06-13 18:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** this should work for your current sample DF, but i'm not sure what would you like to have for alternate ones and zeroes in the `buy` column (for example if you have the following sequence in the `buy` column belonging to the same `id`: 1,0,1,1,0  - what would be your desired output in this case?)

```
In [20]: df.sort_values(['id', 'date'],ascending=[1,0])[df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[1,0]).groupby('id')['buy'].cumsum() < 2]
Out[20]:
        id                date  sec  buy
2  5211153 2016-06-13 18:57:09    2    1
1  5211153 2016-06-13 18:50:54   66    0
7  5211154 2016-06-13 19:00:11   12    1
6  5211154 2016-06-13 18:59:59   11    0
5  5211154 2016-06-13 18:59:34   25    0
4  5211154 2016-06-13 18:59:08   20    0
3  5211154 2016-06-13 18:57:12  118    0
```

**OLD answer:**

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
df.loc[(df.buy==0) & (df.buy.shift(-1)==1)]
```

yields:

```
In [77]: df.loc[(df.buy==0) & (df.buy.shift(-1)==1)]
Out[77]:
        id                date  sec  buy
1  5211153 2016-06-13 18:50:54   66    0
6  5211154 2016-06-13 18:59:59   11    0
```

please post desired data set if you need something else

Comment: I want to print string, where buy == 1 and after that print all strings before that where buy == 0

Comment: @ldevyataykina, can you post a desired output in your question?

Comment: I mean I want to print all string before buy=1 to all id, while `i-n != 1`

Comment: @ldevyataykina, how should look the output if there are multiple ones and zeroes in the `buy` column - for example: 1, 0, 1, 0 (for the same `id`)?

Comment: I want to print string with buy=1 and after it print previous string, where month is equal to string, where buy = 1 (if this string with month = 6, I want to print all previous string with month = 6) and print string with last month(in this case month = 5)